# django REST framework: HTML form returns filename instead of file

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this HTML template

```
<html><body>
<form method="POST">
   {% render_form submitSerializer %}
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
</body></html>
```

this serializer

```
class SubmitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    submittedFile = serializers.FileField()
    class Meta:
        model = Submit
        fields = {'submittedFile', 'result'}
        read_only_fields = {'result'}
```

and this view

```
class SubmitView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({'submitSerializer':submitSerializer}, template_name='singlelesson.html')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        submit = Submit(lesson=lessonInstance, user=self.request.user, submittedFile = self.request.data['submittedFile'])
        serializer = SubmitSerializer(submit)

        #compare_files returns true if two files contain same text
        result = compare_files(correct_solution, self.request.POST.get('submittedFile'))

        serializer.save(result = result)
        return Response({'submitSerializer':serializer}, template_name='singlelesson.html')
```

Problem is that the form uploads not the file but its name and I get type error when comparing the two files. How do I make the form upload the file instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should extract the file from the FILES QueryDict in the request object, not POST. e.g.:

```
self.request.FILES['submittedFile']
```

Or the django-rest-framework way:

```
request.data['submittedFile']
```

For more explanation check out:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser

**EDIT:** Also change form to:

```
<html><body>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% render_form submitSerializer %}
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
</body></html>
```

And SubmitView to:

```
class SubmitView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
...
```

Comment: doesn't help much, `request.FILES` is an empty dictionary and `request.data['submittedFile']` throws the same error. If I add `parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)` as mentioned in documentation, I get 400 bad request on every upload

Comment: Use MultiPartParser instead and also make sure the content-type of the request is set correctly on your form like this: `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: still throws `415 unsupported media type`, but only through browser. If I construct a request in postman, it goes through.

Comment: I tested your code and it worked with both request.FILES and request.data. I have updated my answer to clarify the changes above. If they match your code perhaps sharing your html markup from the browser right before hitting submit?

Comment: Actually, I'm stupid and had a typo somewhere. Thanks for your help!